# Swap position of keys in a dictionary for same value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
cost = {
        (0,1):70,
        (0,2):40,
        (1,2):65
        }
```

I would like a dictionary where the values for the opposite keys are also the same. To clarify,

(0,1):70 is also the same as (1,0):70

I tried to flip the values of the keys using this:

```
for i,j in cost.keys():
    cost [j,i]==cost[i,j]
```

This gives a key error of (1,0) but that is the key that I want the code to add.

I further tried  `cost1 = {tuple(y): x for x, y in cost.keys()}`
This resulted in a TypeError:'int' object not iterable

How can I then further append all the values to a dictionary? Thank you for your time and help.